# Use custom XSL for the default view of a list (Allitems.aspx)

Tags: xslt

I was able to successfully add a custom xsl to the webpart and render it the way I wanted. (I borrowed the example from here: http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-customize-list-view-web-part-using-custom-xslt-in-sharepoint...)

While it is easier me to input the link to a web part by specifying the URL to the XSL Link field in the web part properties panel, it doesn't seem to be straight forward for a list page.

My goal is to to apply the same XSL file to the list view even when user clicks the title of the web part and goes to the actual list view (Allitems.aspx).

I opened up Allitems.aspx in SPD, and found the following tag -

main.xsl

Could I / Should I simply change he main.xsl to my custom file to meet the goal? Something like -

/mySharePoint/customeXSLT/myXSLT.xsl

Just would like to get some confirmation before I actually test it and break things

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, basically the list on the Allitems.aspx is also a web part, so the same thing can be done by editing the page, without going to SPD.